# Okta ApiClient GetList: "Error making an HTTP request: One or more errors occurred"

Tags: c#, okta, okta-api

I am using Okta as my authentication provider, however recently I am getting the above-mentioned exception message *most of the time*, although not always.

I took a look [at the c# wrapper](https://github.com/okta/oktasdk-csharp/blob/master/Okta.Core/Clients/ApiClient.cs), but I still can't figure out why the outcome seems so unreliable.

Anyone knows what is causing this?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, it was a long time ago, I don't have them now. If memory serves me right, it was timing out - I reduced the amount of profiles I retrieve each time and now it's smooth sailing.